# HTML related question/JSX related question

Tags: html

In regular HTML, the attribute used to define classes is 'class'. However, in JSX (the syntax used in React), class is a reserved keyword in JavaScript for defining classes. so what to do instead of write 'class' in JSX file?

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx#3-camelcase-salls-most-of-the-things